# I want to input a fraction into a function in python

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that will calculate the simplified version of a fraction:

```
def simp_frac(num,den):
    smallest = min(num, den)
    for i in range(smallest, 1 , -1):
        if num%i == 0 and den%i == 0:
            print (str(num/i) + "/" + str(den/i))
            break
```

where `print(simp_frac(12,4))` gives me the output I expect, `3/1`.

What I want to do is modify the function so that a user can input a fraction written in the form `a/b`, but I cant figure out what type of variable to use and how to "feed" my function the user input fraction in two separate values, the numerator and denominator.

Comment: get user input to string, split by `/`, and change the values to int or float.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [fractions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) module? I think it does what you're looking for, though I'm not sure if you're implementing this because you need it for something else or because you need to implement the function itself (e.g. for an assignment)

Answer (score 1):

You can ask a user for input data as follows:

```
user_input = input("Provide fraction as num/dem (e.g. 1/3): ")
# in python 2.7: user_input = raw_input("Provide fraction as num/dem (e.g. 1/3): ")

num,den = map(float, user_input.split('/'))

simp_frac(num,den)
```

Comment: I like this answer because it nicely handles extra whitespace in the input. I would just recommend making a note to use `raw_input` for python2.

Comment: @Dan I added raw_input for python 2.

Comment: A `map` seems excessive since I believe python handles whitespaces when converting `str` to numerical types automatically. A simple unpack would suffice.

Comment: @mogambo You need to convert the strings to float/ints. You can use map, or do it "manually" as others did. But map, in general, is more pythonic i think, and even if map is an overkill here, its good for OP to know it for future use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `input()` built-in to prompt the user to enter values. *On Python 2.x, use `raw_input()`*.

Instead of printing your result, simply return it.

```
def simp_frac(num,den):
    smallest = min(num, den)
    for i in range(smallest, 1 , -1):
        if num%i == 0 and den%i == 0:
            return '{}/{}'.format(num/i,den/i)
            # break - not needed

user_input = input('Please enter a fraction: ')
num, den = user_input.split('/')
print('Your result is: {}'.format(simp_frac(int(num), int(den))))
```

We need to convert the input to integers as all input will be submitted as strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
num, den = raw_input().split('/')
simp_frac(float(num), float(den))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple play on string [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method and [splat operator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

```
def simp_frac_string(s):
    return simp_frac(*(int(i) for i in s.split('/')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this type of code helps for calculations.

```
from fractions import Fraction 
x = raw_input('Enter a Fraction: ')
y = Fraction(x)
print(y)
z = y+1.5
print('output:', z)
```

raw_input takes any input as String and Fraction converts it to Float

Sample Input:

```
Enter a Fraction: 3/5
output: 2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Fraction Module in python" as,
`from fractions import Fraction frac = Fraction(raw_input())`